# Accessing HDFS thru spark-scala program

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

I have written a simple program to join the orders and order_items files which are in HDFS.

My Code to read the data:

```
val orders = sc.textFile ("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8022/user/root/retail_db/orders/part-00000")
val orderItems = sc.textFile ("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8022/user/root/retail_db/order_items/part-00000")
```

I got the below exception:

```
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/root/retail_db, expected: file:///**
```

Can you please let me know the issue here? Thanks!!

Comment: it expects file location but you have provided the file path from url i think

Comment: Are you running spark in local mode ?

Comment: yes Afaq, I am running spark in local mode.

Answer (score 2):

You are currently using the Cloudera Quickstart VM, which most likely means you are running Spark 1.6 as those are the parcels that can be installed directly from Cloudera Manager and the default version for CDH 5.x

If that is the case, Spark on Yarn points by default to HDFS so you don't need to specify **hdfs**.

Simply do this:

```
val orderItems = sc.textFile ("/user/cloudera/retail_db/order_items/part-00000")
```

Note I changed also to /user/cloudera. Make sure your current user has permissions.

The **hdfs://** is only if you are using Spark standalone

Comment: @ xmorera I am able to run the code  using **val orders = sc.textFile("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8022/user/root/retail_db/orders/part-00000")** in the terminal. But it is not working thru Intellij. Is there anything that need to remove/add when I run thru Intellij.

Comment: Are you creating the context? When you open the terminal the context is created for you, but outside of the shell you need to do the initialization yourself.